# Paraconjugate of polynomial

Tags: functions, complex, polynomials

I'm trying to obtain the paraconjugate of a polynomial with the following code,

```
f11[s_] := 0.0449 + 0.0629*s + 0.7673*s^2 + 0.4982*s^3 + 1.7570*s^4 + 0.5108*s^5 + s^6
Refine[Conjugate[f11[-s]], {Element[s, Complexes], Re[s] == 0, Im[s] > 0}]
```

but it outputs,

```
Out[238]= 0.0449 - 0.0629 Conjugate[s] + 0.7673 Conjugate[s]^2 - 0.4982 Conjugate[s]^3 + 1.757 Conjugate[s]^4 - 0.5108 Conjugate[s]^5 + Conjugate[s]^6
```

I was expecting that Mathematica would drop the *Conjugate[]* from the response, as i'm saying that *s* is a pure imaginary with a positive signal. Is this correct? Am I doing this in the correct manner?

Comment: Maybe `Refine[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f11[-s]], s] /. Im[s] -> s, {Re[s] == 0, Im[s] > 0}]`

Comment: Thank you @Coolwater! I think the correct would be `Simplify[Refine[
  ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f11[-s]], s] /. Im[s] -> s/I, {Re[s] == 0, 
   Im[s] > 0}]]`, but this result is different from what I was expecting. I should revise the theory.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the very long delay: more than 4 years after the original inquiry. It seems the paraconjugate polynomial of `f11[s]` can be formed as

```
f11paraconj[s] =
 = Expand[ FromDigits[Reverse[Conjugate[CoefficientList[f11[s],s]]],-s] ] =
 = 0.0449 - 0.0629 s + 0.7673 s^2 - 0.4982 s^3 + 1.757 s^4 - 0.5108 s^5 + s^6
```

The roots of `f11` and `f11paraconj` show the required symmetry with respect to the imaginary axis of the complex s-plane, that is, their real parts have opposite signs. (Works in Mathematica 13.)

Comment: Could you show your results and supporting computation, applied to the polynomial in the question?

Comment: In order to make the post readable, please format code properly as well.

Comment: I recommend you edit your answer to include this additional information.

Comment: Of course, if the coefficients are all real, then the conjugation is not actually needed.

Comment: If P(s) is a real-coefficient polynomial, its paraconjugate polynomial is simply P(-s).